# Store game card data in a single or multiple XML?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, excel

I need to turn Excel data I have here for about 5,000 trading cards(name, play cost, power/rules, health, type) in order to use it for my game done in Flash and ActionScript 3.0.

Keep in mind that there are different types of cards(ability, quest, equipment(armor, weapon, item), ally, hero, etc...)

So, I was wondering whether I should dump it all in one XML file or have many different XML files?

EDIT:

I will be using the data for creating/managing the player's card decks and displaying cards during the match.

[The card database](http://tcgbrowser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the trading cards are related and share the same properties (for example if the ability card and quest card both have 'name' and 'health' properties), then I would have them all in one XML file.

If the different types have different properties (e.g. weapon card has 'strength' and 'defense' properties, and hero card has 'name' and 'health' properties), then perhaps it's better to have an XML file per card type.

If you're going to deploy your project to the web, you want to be careful that the size of your XML file isn't too big or your users will be having to wait for the XML to be loaded.

Comment: There are many different card sets. Wouldn't having multiple XML files be more reasonable because players will download only those XML files that are needed, and not an entire data of 5k cards. I also have HD images for each card.

Comment: Yeah, I missed your comment about card types. I edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Alright. And as for the card set information(to which set a particular card belongs and its number within the set)should be specified for each card as an attribute/node?

Comment: Yes, you can specify set-specific data in either an attribute or node (your preference). The point is to keep the schema the same among all your files so that it's easy to read any of them in with the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use Separate small XML files, If :

- **The xml files are independent :** The data of a level in a game, which
  might not be required at all, once the user clears the level, is
  independent.
- **Some xml is common & used in a mixed manner :** The browser can cache the small files & hence avoid downloading the commonly used files again.
- **You need to occasionally update specific regions :** This allows the rest of the XML to stay cached & forcing specific file to be updated, by modifying the query part of URL.

Comment: There are no levels. You make a deck of 60 cards, click "Find match" and play against another player.

Comment: Still, if it is possible for you to maintain multiple XML, then better  go with it.